# How do I remove all occurrences of {root, leaf} from classes in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I am currently recreating a bunch of class diagrams from Rational Rose in Enterprise Architect, and as a result from the converting, almost all of the classes have tags like `{root}`, `{leaf}`, `{root,leaf}`.

Is there any way I can remove all of these without having to go though every class and unchecking the `Is Root` and `Is Leaf` checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Diagram Properties dialog, there is an option "Show Element Property String". You can switch this off for each diagram.

Alternatively, you could export your model to XMI, open it in a text editor, do a search-and-replace to remove all occurrences of isroot="true" and isleaf="true", and then re-import the XMI.

Comment: Thank you :) Hiding them is good enough for me, and your first solution worked great, didn't try the second.